# How to create a tlslite-ng server with TLS 1.3 support only?

Tags: ssl, certificate, python-3.5, python-3.6

I would like to write a server/client TLS1.3 set of scripts in Python. Therefore, I use [tlslite-ng](https://github.com/tomato42/tlslite-ng/blob/master/tests/tlstest.py) library as only one which has [TLS1.3 on board](https://github.com/tlswg/tls13-spec/wiki/Implementations).

However, even my simple code fails:

```
#openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.pem -out certificate.pem
#
import os
import socket
#import sys
from tlslite.api import *

s = open("./certificate.pem").read()
x509 = X509()
x509.parse(s)
certChain = X509CertChain([x509])
#print (certChain)

s = open("./privateKey.pem").read()
privateKey = parsePEMKey(s, private=True)
#print (privateKey)


host = '127.0.1.1'  
port = 8888
payload = 1500
server_address = (host, port) 



def start_TLS_server():

    socket_TLS = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_TLS.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socket_TLS.bind(server_address)
    socket_TLS.listen(1)

    #synchro = synchroSocket.accept()

    connection = TLSConnection(socket_TLS)

    settings = HandshakeSettings()
    settings.minKeySize = 2048
    settings.cipherNames = ["aes256"]
    settings.minVersion = (3,1)
    connection.handshakeServer(certChain=certChain, privateKey=privateKey, reqCert=True, settings=settings)
    #connection.session.clientCertChain   # X509CertChain
    #connection.session.serverCertChain   # X509CertChain
    print(connection)

    print("TLS server is running...")

    while True:
        data = connection.read(payload)
        if not data: 
            break
        connection.write(data)

    connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_TLS_server()
```

I'm getting error like this:

```
root@Admin-PC:/mnt/c/Users/andre/Documents/Visual Studio Code/Projects/SSNProject/TLSvsNPF# python3 TLSserver.py
<tlslite.tlsconnection.TLSConnection object at 0x7f0c9142fe48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TLSserver.py", line 89, in <module>
    start_TLS_server()
  File "TLSserver.py", line 58, in start_TLS_server
    connection.handshakeServer(certChain=certChain, privateKey=privateKey, reqCert=True, settings=settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsconnection.py", line 1191, in handshakeServer
    nextProtos=nextProtos, anon=anon, alpn=alpn, sni=sni):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsconnection.py", line 1220, in handshakeServerAsync
    for result in self._handshakeWrapperAsync(handshaker, checker):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsconnection.py", line 2216, in _handshakeWrapperAsync
    for result in handshaker:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsconnection.py", line 1262, in _handshakeServerAsyncHelper
    anon, alpn, sni):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsconnection.py", line 1485, in _serverGetClientHello
    HandshakeType.client_hello):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsrecordlayer.py", line 657, in _getMsg
    for result in self._getNextRecord():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsrecordlayer.py", line 829, in _getNextRecord
    for result in self._getNextRecordFromSocket():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/tlsrecordlayer.py", line 853, in _getNextRecordFromSocket
    for result in self._recordLayer.recvRecord():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/recordlayer.py", line 695, in recvRecord
    for result in self._recordSocket.recv():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/recordlayer.py", line 188, in recv
    for record in self._recvHeader():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/recordlayer.py", line 122, in _recvHeader
    for result in self._sockRecvAll(1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/recordlayer.py", line 99, in _sockRecvAll
    socketBytes = self.sock.recv(length - len(buf))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tlslite/bufferedsocket.py", line 54, in recv
    return self.socket.recv(bufsize)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
root@Admin-PC:/mnt/c/Users/andre/Documents/Visual Studio Code/Projects/SSNProject/TLSvsNPF#
```

As you may notice I am on Windows 10's Linux subsutem Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I understand that mistake is somewhere in certificates but it is not clear where... Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

you need to call `accept()` on the listening socket to get the socket and connection info which you wrap `TLSConnection` around.

See [`tlstest.py`](https://github.com/tomato42/tlslite-ng/blob/adf706a390df98185a2ec00c92ea19beb823d9e0/tests/tlstest.py#L836-L853) for an example.

Do note that you need to use the [`tls-1.3`](https://github.com/tomato42/tlslite-ng/tree/tls-1.3) branch for the TLS 1.3 support to be present, and `aes256` cipher is incompatible with TLS 1.3 (aes256 is a name used for CBC mode cipher, no CBC mode ciphers are defined for TLS 1.3, you need to use `aes256gcm` or one of the other AEAD ciphers)